# Can a willing lycanthrope be True Polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, polymorph

Can a lycanthrope or other shapeshifter be willingly affected by the spell True Polymorph? I know that it can be affected by regular Polymorph, but the text for the enhanced version seems to differ.

Answer (score 11):

No, a Shapchanger such as a Lycanthrope can not be affected by True Polymorph; regardless of it being a willing target or not.

The text of Polymorph says an **unwilling** creature must make a saving throw against the spell.  Shapechangers automatically succeed on the save.

This *could* be taken to mean that if the Shapechanger is *willing*, there is no save for it to automatically succeed against and it is thus affected. The text of True Polymorph differs in stating quite directly that Shapechangers are flat out unaffected by this spell, instead of automatically succeeding on the saving throw.  A creature that is unaffected by a spell, willing or otherwise, is immune to its effects.

Comment: Hi Airatome, I revised this answer slightly to push something into the second paragraph I believe you were trying to highlight, where a particular theoretical possibility is closed off by the True Polymorph Rules. Could you check if that still reflects what you want this answer to say, and revise further or roll back as appropriate?

Comment: Reads perfectly to me :)